# How to use suggest box for numbers

Tags: google-app-maker

I'm trying to add a field on my form that suggests different ID's in the database. I'm getting the error suggest_field.ID does not support the startsWith function. Is there any way to change this so that I can use the Suggest box with numbers

Answer (score 0):

Since your IDs are integers and not strings they do not have a startsWith function.  You can use `(@datasource.items..Id).map(String)` as your suggest box options and then autocomplete would work.  Just be careful with value bindings as the types will not match - you may have to ditch bindings for value and use the `onAttach` and `onValueChange` events to convert the type to/from an integer and then set your datasource item's ID value (use `parseInt(string)` to convert a string to a number type and use `number.toString()` to convert a number to a string).